# Copy Array of pointers inside a struct using CUDA

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct, cuda

I wish to copy an array of pointers from one struct to another. The Struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct COORD3D
{
    int x,y,z;
}
COORD3D;

typedef struct structName
{
    double *volume;
    COORD3D size;
    // .. some other vars
}
structName;
```

I wish to do this inside a function where I pass in the address of an empty instance of the struct and the address of the struct with the data I wish to copy. Currently I do this serially via:

```
void foo(structName *dest, structName *source)
{

    // .. some other work

    int size = source->size.x * source->size.y * source->size.z;
    dest->volume = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
       dest->volume[i] = source->volume[i];
}
```

I want to do this in CUDA to speed up the process (as the array is very large [~12 million elements].

I have tried the following however, although the code compiles and runs, I get incorrect results stored in the array (seems to be very large random numbers)

```
void foo(structName *dest, structName *source)
{
    // .. some other work

    int size = source->size.x * source->size.y * source->size.z;
    dest->volume = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));

    // Device Pointers
    double *DEVICE_SOURCE, *DEVICE_DEST;

    // Declare memory on GPU 
    cudaMalloc(&DEVICE_DEST,size);
    cudaMalloc(&DEVICE_SOURCE,size);

    // Copy Source to GPU
    cudaMemcpy(DEVICE_SOURCE,source->volume,size,
               cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Setup Blocks/Grids
    dim3 dimGrid(ceil(source->size.x/10.0),
                 ceil(source->size.y/10.0),
                 ceil(source->size.z/10.0));
    dim3 dimBlock(10,10,10);

    // Run CUDA Kernel
    copyVol<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>> (DEVICE_SOURCE,
                                   DEVICE_DEST,
                                   source->size.x,
                                   source->size.y,
                                   source->size.z);

    // Copy Constructed Array back to Host
    cudaMemcpy(dest->volume,DEVICE_DEST,size,
               cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

}
```

The Kernel looks like this:

```
__global__ void copyVol(double *source, double *dest,
                        int x, int y, int z)
{
    int posX = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int posY = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int posZ = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if (posX < x && posY < y && posZ < z)
    {
        dest[posX+(posY*x)+(posZ*y*x)] =
        source[posX+(posY*x)+(posZ*y*x)];
    }   
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `malloc(source->size,sizeof(double));` does not compile.

Comment: Sorry that is a typo, will edit now

Comment: Yes there was a var name incorrect, there are no typos now (my apologies!)

Comment: You have used `malloc()` twice, and neither will compile. `malloc()` takes one argument.

Comment: Sorry my heads not in the right place today (I forgot to change it from when I debugged using calloc()) I'm 99% sure everything is correct now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am risking a wrong answer, but have you left out the size of the data type?

```
cudaMalloc(&DEVICE_DEST,size);
```

should be

```
cudaMalloc(&DEVICE_DEST,size*sizeof(double));
```

Also

```
cudaMemcpy(DEVICE_SOURCE,source->volume,size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

should be

```
cudaMemcpy(DEVICE_SOURCE,source->volume,size*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

and so on.